# Nach welcher Regel kann man bestimmen, ob die Vorsilbe eines trennbaren Verbes in der Mitte des Haupsatztes stehen darf?

Tags: grammaticality, separable-verb

Laut Grammatikbüchern steht die Vorsilbe eines trennbaren Verbes am Ende des Haupsatzes. Ich habe aber im Wörterbuch dieses Beispiel gesehen:

> Gib doch nicht so an mit deinem neuen Auto!

Ich weiß, dass es *immer* richtig ist, die Vorsilbe ans Ende des Haupsatzes zu bringen. Ich will aber wissen, wann und nach welcher Regel man sie in die Mitte des Satzes bringen darf?

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin schon mal im Voraus *kein Muttersprachler*. Allerdings besitze ich das Goethe-Zertifikat C2, wohne in Deutschland, und werde oft für einen Muttersprachler gehalten. Das sage ich nicht nur, weil ich mich cool finde, sondern auch, um Einwänden vorzubeugen, da mein Sprachgefühl nicht unbedingt so aussagekräftig ist, wie das eines Muttersprachlers.

Zur Frage:

Das ist tatsächlich nur eine Tendenz. [Es kann vieles im Hauptsatz nach der rechten "Satzklammer" stehen, im sogennanten Nachfeld](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Nachfeld.html). Auf der verlinkten Seite (canoonet) stehen die wichtigsten Regeln. Meistens sind es lange Präpositionalphrasen.

Im Alltag kann sogar unter anderem die Zeitangabe (quasi als "Nachgedanke") am Ende des Satzes auftreten, je nach Betonung (<-- zB so!). Da hat mich sehr geschockt, weil einem ja immer im Unterricht gesagt wird, und man immer in Grammatikbüchern (wie deinem) die Regel vorfindet, dass die Zeitangabe *immer* nach dem Verb käme (bzw. nach der [Wackernagelposition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wackernagels_Gesetz)).

Ein Beispiel aus meinen Whatsapp-Chats mit der Zeitangabe nach der rechten Satzklammer (in deinem Fall nach dem Adverbialpräfix eines trennbaren Verbs):

> Ah okay, ich muss morgen halt arbeiten. Deswegen kann ich auch nicht eskalieren heute.
>
> Hat jemand Lust auf nen Kaffee im *(Lokal)* jetzt?

Beide stammen von Muttersprachlern, ich sehe und sage so etwas ständig. Ob das gutes Deutsch ist, sei dahingestellt. In der Schriftsprache habe ich solches meines Wissens kein einziges Mal gesehen, vermutlich weil es daran liegt, dass solche Zeitangaben, wie gesagt, nur als "vergessenen Inhalt" nachgefügt werden, und wenn sich der Sprecher noch ein Momentchen länger überlegt hätte, was er zu sagen hat, hätte er die Zeitangabe auch ganz nach vorne gestellt, wo sie hingehört.

Ich hoffe das hat geholfen!

Comment: A quote from this page, today: „Da müssen wir klar miteinander sein in der Gesellschaft.“
https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article206578991/Coronavirus-Spahn-Das-wird-eher-viele-Monate-so-gehen-als-viele-Wochen.html

Comment: Die Beispiele einer Nachstellung, die du oben gibst, kommen aus der (mündlichen) Umgangssprache. Es gibt aber daneben auch in (stilistisch guter) Schriftsprache Fälle, wo die "Schulbuch-Satzstellung" durchbrochen wird. Schöne Beispiele dafür - plus Hinweise darauf, wann man dieses Stilmittel einsetzen sollte -  findet man in Ludwig Reiners' Buch "Stilfibel", erste Ausgabe 1950, dann immer wieder aufgelegt.

Comment: Echt cool! Das schau ich mir bestimmt an, danke.